# C++ performance weirdness w/ OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, g++, gprof

I am rewriting some rendering C code in C++. The old C code basically computes everything it needs and renders it at each frame. The new C++ code instead pre-computes what it needs and stores that as a linked list.

Now, actual rendering operations are translations, colour changes and calls to GL lists.

While executing the operations in the linked list should be pretty straightforward, it would appear that the resulting method call takes longer than the old version (which computes everything each time - I have of course made sure that the new version isn't recomputing).

The weird thing? It executes less OpenGL operations than the old version. But it gets weirder. When I added counters for each type of operation, and a good old printf at the end of the method, it *got faster* - both gprof and manual measurements confirm this.

I also bothered to take a look at the assembly code generated by G++ in both cases (with and without trace), and there is no major change (which was my initial suspicion) - the only differences are a few more stack words allocated for counters, increasing said counters, and preparing for printf followed by a jump to it.

Also, this holds true with both -O2 and -O3. I am using gcc 4.4.5 and gprof 2.20.51 on Ubuntu Maverick.

I guess my question is: what's happening? What am I doing wrong? Is something throwing off both my measurements and gprof?

Comment: So what the profiling tells about the version with no counters? BTW I recommend valgrind+callgrind as a profiler, and kcachegrind as the visualisation tool.

Comment: In the version without counters, the average time for the rendering function is 0.02ms (total). In the version with counters, it does not register (0.00ms total). Thanks, I'll try valgrind (but last time I tried using it for memory leaks checks on the same program, it was causing crashes w/ the proprietary nVidia drivers).

Comment: I'd also try to get a detailed profile, down to individual lines of the source code.

Comment: If it was so simple to profile, everyone would put random counters :P

Comment: Timing each OpenGL call only measures how long it takes to add operations to the execution batch. But what really matters in your case is the total rendering time which is the time from the first OpenGL call of a frame up to the finishing glFinish call. I'm pretty sure that if you compare both versions of your program those additional time required for OpenGL calls in the one version will compensate with longer time until glFinish() returns in the other version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By spending time in printf, you may be avoiding stalls in your next OpenGL call.

Comment: My next OpenGL call is another, totally unrelated function, so it would have no influence on that specific function. I could try putting a printf between calls to both test functions, it might point to that problem.

Comment: Definitely looks like you're right. I inverted the calls between my 2 functions, and the profiling results have been inverted as well.

Answer (score 1):

Without more information, it is difficult to know what is happening here, but here are a few hints:

- Are you sure the OpenGL calls are the same? You can use some tool to compare the calls issued. Make sure there was no state change introduced by the possibly different order things are done.
- Have you tried to use a profiler at runtime? If you have many objects, the simple fact of chasing pointers while looping over the list could introduce cache misses.
- Have you identified a particular bottleneck, either on the CPU side or GPU side?

Here is my own guess on what could be going wrong. The calls you send to your GPU take some time to complete: the previous code, by mixing CPU operations and GPU calls, made CPU and GPU work in parallel; on the contrary the new code first makes the CPU computes many things while the GPU is idling, then feeds the GPU with all the work to get done while the CPU has nothing left to do.